# How to print the first name and initials of a full name

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I'm not sure on how to print the first name and initials when the user inputs their full name.
For example, if the user inputs "john doe", it should print out "Greetings, John, your initials are JD"

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter full name: ");
     String fullName = reader.nextLine();

     System.out.print("Greetings, " + getFirstName(fullName) + ", your initials are " + getInitials(fullName));
   }

   public static String getFirstName(String fullName) {
      return fullName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + fullName.substring(1).toLowerCase();
   }
   
   public static String getInitials(String fullName) {
      return fullName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
   }
}
```

Thank you for your help and suggestions!

Comment: Java and JavaScript are different.  Read here to know the difference https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-java-and-javascript/

Comment: sorry about that, just revised. i mix them up sometimes, thank you for letting me know

Comment: Note: please see [mcve]. Make sure your question includes expected and actual output, in a way that is easily to be found. Adding comments in your code isnt too helpful ... many people might not scroll to the right and see that stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In order to get the first name, you can get the substring from index `0` till the first whitespace (i.e. `fullName.indexOf(' '))`
2. In order to get the initials, you can **get the first char of the string** + **the first char after the last whitespace** (i.e. `fullName.lastIndexOf(' ')`).

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter full name: ");
        String fullName = reader.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Greetings, " + getFirstName(fullName) + ", your initials are " + getInitials(fullName));
    }

    public static String getFirstName(String fullName) {
        return fullName.substring(0, fullName.indexOf(' '));
    }

    public static String getInitials(String fullName) {
        int idxLastWhitespace = fullName.lastIndexOf(' ');
        return fullName.substring(0, 1) + fullName.substring(idxLastWhitespace + 1, idxLastWhitespace + 2);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter full name: Arvind Kumar Avinash
Greetings, Arvind, your initials are AA
```

Comment: You can replace fullName.subString(0,1) with fullName.charAt(0). It is a more optimal solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can split your string at all blanks and use the first entry of the array as your first name using the method split of String.
For the initials you just use all entries of the array.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is break the `fullname` into a String array as such.

```
String[] names = fullName.split("\\s+"); //splits fullname at each space
```

Then you can use a loop to uppercase each part of the name

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    // do your toUpperCasing stuff here 
}
```